# LXC Container cannot access LAN OR Internet

Tags: networking, lxc

I am trying to setup a Linux Container using bridged networking.

Here's how I setup my bridge: http://www.ericsbinaryworld.com/2016...he-connection/

Here's how I installed the container: http://www.ericsbinaryworld.com/2016...etting-up-lxc/

When I use `lxc-attach -n lemmy` to get into the container, I don't have internet access within the container.

Did I forget an easy step?

This is running in a KVM VM that is using macvtap and that the VM itself is able to access the net.

Other relevant info/things I've done to try and debug the problem.

Host OS: Fedora 24.
VM: CentOS 7 - named Airship
Inside of Airship, a container - named Lemmy.

First round of debugging:
I started the VM - Airship.
Logged into Airship as root.

```
ping www.google.com
```

works.

```
lxc-start -n lemmy -d
lxc-attach -n lemmy
```

Now I'm inside the container.

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

gets me

```
connect: Network is unreachable
```

So I did an ip a and it looks like the interface isn't up.
Did a check of systemctl status network.service and apparently it was in a failed state.
When I tried a systemctl start network.service it just stays there without seeming to finish.

Second round of debugging:
When I did a systemctl status network.service - it looks like it was stalling on trying to get a DHCP address.
So I edited the following file:

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
```

To have:

```
DEVICE=eth0
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR="192.168.1.36"
PREFIX="24"
GATEWAY="192.168.1.1"
DNS1="192.168.1.7"
DOMAIN="mushroomkingdom"
HOSTNAME=
NM_CONTROLLED=no
TYPE=Ethernet
MTU=
```

So now it comes up and has an IP address. But I can't reach anyone local or internet.

Dmesg shows:

```
[ 3932.778454] virbr0: port 2(vethFXTSQ3) entered forwarding state
[ 4089.412588] virbr0: received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
```

It can ping itself and the host.

```
[root@lemmy ~]# ping 192.168.1.36
PING 192.168.1.36 (192.168.1.36) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.36: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.030 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.36: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.034 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.36: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.019 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.36: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.031 ms

[root@lemmy ~]# ping 192.168.1.35
PING 192.168.1.35 (192.168.1.35) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.35: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.085 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.35: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.047 ms
```

But if I try my local DNS:

```
[root@lemmy ~]# ping 192.168.1.7
PING 192.168.1.7 (192.168.1.7) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.36 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.36 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.36 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Other things you might ask for:

```
[root@airship ~]# lxc-info -n lemmy
Name: lemmy
State: RUNNING
PID: 3802
IP: 192.168.1.36
CPU use: 0.18 seconds
BlkIO use: 92.50 KiB
Memory use: 1.11 MiB
KMem use: 0 bytes
Link: vethFXTSQ3
TX bytes: 3.24 KiB
RX bytes: 54.10 KiB
Total bytes: 57.34 KiB
```

and on the VM hosting the container:

```
[root@airship ~]# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
link/ether 52:54:00:3d:99:5c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.254.214/24 brd 192.168.254.255 scope global dynamic ens4
   valid_lft 2308sec preferred_lft 2308sec
inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe3d:995c/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master virbr0 state UP qlen 1000
link/ether 52:54:00:64:f5:67 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: virbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP
link/ether 52:54:00:64:f5:67 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.1.35/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global virbr0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe64:f567/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: vethFXTSQ3@if7: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master virbr0 state UP qlen 1000
link/ether fe:6f:c5:df:0e:e1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
inet6 fe80::fc6f:c5ff:fedf:ee1/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

and:

```
[root@airship ~]# brctl show
bridge name bridge id           STP enabled interfaces
virbr0      8000.52540064f567      no         eth0 
                                             vethFXTSQ3
```